# How to stub (to bypass) a Sailsjs auth policy to allow for controller testing?

Tags: testing, sails.js

I have a Sailsjs controller that does some stuff, but currently it is under a policy that requires authentication (i.e. `isAuthenticated`).

Before having applied that policy, the integration test for my controller worked fine. Now it will not work because it requires the user to login.

For reasons not stated, I cannot make a request to login before each test, so I have to find a way to skip that policy. I would like to stub it so it always lets the route go through. How would you do that in Sailsjs v0.12.11?

Comment: Just make check for environment inside your policy. And run tests on test environment. So add if(process.env === 'test') return next(); to your policy logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an API key in your isAuthenticated method and check for this key. If the key is available, call the next() function.

Code snippet:

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
if (req.isAuthenticated() || req.headers['api-key'] == 'apiKeyValue') {
    return next();
} else {
    if (!req.headers['api-key'] && !req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return res.redirect('/auth/login');
    } else {
        res.status(403);
        return res.json({
            error: 'Invalid Api Key'
        });
    }
}
```

So essentially, pass an API key via header and modify the logic in isAuthenticated function. So whenever the API key is available, it will call the next() callback.